# ng-repeat only showing 2 elements of array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, reddit

The ng-repeat is only showing the first 2 elements of the array (there are 25).   What is wrong?

I'm a newbie with Angular.  I am lost with the cause of it, no errors in console.  Any suggestions?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" id="posts" ng-controller="myCtrl as posts">
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts" track by $index>
        <p>{{posts.data.children[$index].data.ups}}</p>
        <p>{{posts.data.children[$index].data.title}}</p>
    </li>

</div>


<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.mydata = [];

        $http.get("http:/www.reddit.com/.json")
            .then(function(response) {
                vm.mydata = response.data;
                $scope.posts = vm.mydata;
                //console.log(vm.mydata);
                //console.table(vm.mydata);

            }, function(response) {
                $scope.posts = "Something went wrong";
            });
    });
</script>
```

Final code corrected.  This is a very basic script to manage the extraction of posts in the Reddit's front page and displayed it in descending order by upvotes.  Thank you all for your help!   See code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- _________________________________________________________-->
<!--  Framework:    AngularJs                                 -->
<!--  Author:       Vanessa Torres                            -->
<!--  Date:         March 30, 2016                            -->
<!--  Description:  Reddit's Front page posts extraction      -->
<!-- _________________________________________________________-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" id="posts" ng-controller="myCtrl as posts">
        <li ng-repeat="post in posts.data.children | orderBy:'-data.ups'" track by $index>
            <p>{{post.data.ups}}</p>
            <p>{{post.data.title}}</p>
            <p>{{post.data.url}}</p>
        </li>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.posts = [];

            $http.get("http:/www.reddit.com/.json")
                .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.posts = response.data;
                    console.table(vm.mydata);
                    // 
                }, function(response) {
                    $scope.posts = "Something went wrong";
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add your array with 25 elements.

Comment: Can you post your response?

Comment: use `ng-repeat="post in posts.data.children"` coz the post has only 2 fields whereas you actually are listing the children nodes.

Comment: You probably could assign response data directly to $scope.posts rather than first assigning it to vm.mydata. not an answer but an improvement to your code.

Comment: @immirza you are right I fixed the code, now is cleaner.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are iterating over **posts** which have basically two properties only **ups** and **title**

Use:

```
   <li ng-repeat="post in posts.data.children" track by $index>
        <p>{{post.data.ups}}</p>
        <p>{{post.title}}</p>
    </li>
```

Comment: According to coding standards answer by @madhukar is more accurate

Answer (score 3):

The HTML should be as given below:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" id="posts" ng-controller="myCtrl as posts">
  <li ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index">
    <p>{{post.data.children.data.ups}}</p>
    <p>{{post.data.children.data.title}}</p>
  </li>
</div>
```

This iterates inside the `posts` array and the value of each post keys (`ups` and `title`) is displayed. Please check the documentation for `ng-repeat` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for the correct format of using `track by $index`.

As a basic coding standard, you need not use `var vm = this;` along with `$scope`. If you are using the `vm` variable, then inside routes (or inside directives), where you associate each route (or directive) with a controller, you can add an extra field `controllerAs` for aliasing the controller. Use this alias name in the HTML code to access the `vm` variable. In your example, you can change it as given below:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" id="posts" ng-controller="myCtrl as postsCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="post in postsCtrl.posts track by $index">
    <p>{{post.data.children.data.ups}}</p>
    <p>{{post.data.children.data.title}}</p>
  </li>
</div>
```

And in the scripts tag:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($http) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.posts = '';

  $http.get("http:/www.reddit.com/.json")
    .then(function(response) {
      vm.posts = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
      vm.posts = 'Something went wrong';
    });
});
</script>
```